# wordpress redirect 1 wordpress site to custome site on the same domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have 2 sites on the same domain, 1 site is WordPress and the other isn't. when i type URL

`http://example.com/mysite2`

then i get error from WordPress site. 404 not found. my site 2 is custom website(none WordPress) and i have some custom data which is not supported by WordPress that's why i need redirection also i try to search but i can't found any thing helpful because i am not use WordPress below script i found from another web but not work

`RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite1/(.*)$ [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite2/(.*)$ [OR] RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L] </IfModule>`

anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after search my issue i don't find solution on Google then i decide to create new sub domain and put my none WordPress website there and its work